# Проблема с подключением к CRM Dynamics 365

Tags: c#, crm

При обращении к CRM MS Dynamics 365 on-premise при попытке прочитать данные из CRM время от времени выскакивает такая ошибка:

**System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: At least one security token in the message could not be validated.**

Пробовал игнорировать сертификат таким способом:

*ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;*

-- не помогло. Ошибка всё так же появляется. Причём, не регулярно, а как-то спорадически - то долгое время всё работает нормально, то несколько запросов подряд выдают такую ошибку.
CRM и web-приложение расположены в одной сети, и даже физически на одном сервере. Данных немного, заведомо меньше 5 000 записей. От запроса не зависит - один и тот же запрос может и пройти нормально, и выдать описанную выше ошибку.

Что можно посмотреть? В какую сторону копать?